# Google Maps Two Circles Intersection Points

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

Is there an easy way to get the `lat`/`lng` of the intersection points (if available) of two [circles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) in [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)? Or should I go with the [hard](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-2-circles) way?

**EDIT :** In my problem, circles always have the same radius, in case that makes the solution easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, for equal circles rather simple solution could be elaborated:
Let's first circle center is A point, second circle center is F, midpoint is C, and intersection points are B,D. ABC is right-angle spherical triangle with right angle C.

[image]

We want to find angle A - this is deviation angle from A-F direction. Spherical trigonometry (Napier's rules for right spherical triangles) gives us formula:

`cos(A)= tg(AC) * ctg(AB)`
where one symbol denote spherical angle, double symbols denote great circle arcs' angles (AB, AC). We can see that AB = circle radius (in radians, of course), AC = half-distance between A and F on the great circle arc.
To find AC (and other values) -  I'll use code [from this excellent page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
```

and our

```
AC = c/2
```

If circle radius Rd is given is kilometers, then

```
AB = Rd / R = Rd / 6371
```

Now we can find angle

```
A = arccos(tg(AC) * ctg(AB))
```

Starting bearing (AF direction):

```
var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
        Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

Intersection points' bearings:

```
B_bearing = brng - A
D_bearing = brng + A
```

Intersection points' coordinates:

```
var latB = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(Rd/R) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(Rd/R)*Math.cos(B_bearing) );
var lonB = lon1.toRad() + Math.atan2(Math.sin(B_bearing)*Math.sin(Rd/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(Rd/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

and the same for D_bearing

latB, lonB are in radians

Comment: Unfortunately, the function doesn't work property (most likely I am missing something). Can you please check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rNW76/18/ and let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: Note that lon1 in your 'lonSol1 = ...` expression is still in degrees, but atan2 returns radians!

Comment: I fixed it here http://jsfiddle.net/rNW76/24/ but still doesn't show the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

The [computation the "hard" way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-2-circles) can be simplified for the case r1 = r2 =: r. We still first have to convert the circle centers P1,P2 from (lat,lng) to Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z).

```
var DEG2RAD = Math.PI/180;
function LatLng2Cartesian(lat_deg,lng_deg)
{
  var lat_rad = lat_deg*DEG2RAD;
  var lng_rad = lng_deg*DEG2RAD;
  var cos_lat = Math.cos(lat_rad);
  return {x: Math.cos(lng_rad)*cos_lat,
          y: Math.sin(lng_rad)*cos_lat,
          z: Math.sin(lat_rad)};
}

var P1 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat1, lng1);
var P2 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat2, lng2);
```

But the intersection line of the planes holding the circles can be computed more easily. Let `d` be the distance of the actual circle center (in the plane) to the corresponding point P1 or P2 on the surface. A simple derivation shows (with R the earth's radius):

```
var R = 6371; // earth radius in km
var r = 100; // the direct distance (in km) of the given points to the intersections points
// if the value rs for the distance along the surface is known, it has to be converted:
// var r = 2*R*Math.sin(rs/(2*R*Math.PI));
var d = r*r/(2*R);
```

Now let S1 and S2 be the intersections points and S their mid-point. With `s = |OS|` and `t = |SS1| = |SS2|` (where O = (0,0,0) is the earth's center) we get from simple derivations:

```
var a = Math.acos(P1.x*P2.x + P1.y*P2.y + P1.z*P2.z); // the angle P1OP2
var s = (R-d)/Math.cos(a/2);
var t = Math.sqrt(R*R - s*s);
```

Now since `r1 = r2` the points S, S1, S2 are in the mid-plane between P1 and P2. For `v_s = OS` we get:

```
function vecLen(v)
{ return Math.sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y + v.z*v.z); }
function vecScale(scale,v)
{ return {x: scale*v.x, y: scale*v.y, z: scale*v.z}; }

var v = {x: P1.x+P2.x, y: P1.y+P2.y, z:P1.z+P2.z}; // P1+P2 is in the middle of OP1 and OP2
var S = vecScale(s/vecLen(v), v);

function crossProd(v1,v2)
{
  return {x: v1.y*v2.z - v1.z*v2.y,
          y: v1.z*v2.x - v1.x*v2.z,
          z: v1.x*v2.y - v1.y*v2.x};
}
var n = crossProd(P1,P2); // normal vector to plane OP1P2 = vector along S1S2
var SS1 = vecScale(t/vecLen(n),n);

var S1 = {x: S.x+SS1.x, y: S.y+SS1.y, z: S.z+SS1.z}; // S + SS1
var S2 = {x: S.x-SS1.x, y: S.y-SS2.y, z: S.z-SS1.z}; // S - SS1
```

Finally we have to convert back to (lat,lng):

```
function Cartesian2LatLng(P)
{
  var P_xy = {x: P.x, y:P.y, z:0}
  return {lat: Math.atan2(P.y,P.x)/DEG2RAD, lng: Math.atan2(P.z,vecLen(P_xy))/DEG2RAD};
}
var S1_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S1);
var S2_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yazanpro, sorry for the late response on this.

You may be interested in a concise variant of MBo's approach, which simplifies in two respects :

- firstly by exploiting some of the built in features of the google.maps API to avoid much of the hard math.
- secondly by using a 2D model for the calculation of the included angle, in place of MBo's spherical model. I was initially uncertain about the validity of this simplification but satisfied myself with tests in [a fork of MBo's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb92k/) that the errors are minor at all but the largest of circles with respect to the size of the Earth (eg at low zoom levels).

Here's the function :

```
function getIntersections(circleA, circleB) {
    /* 
     * Find the points of intersection of two google maps circles or equal radius
     * circleA: a google.maps.Circle object 
     * circleB: a google.maps.Circle object
     * returns: null if 
     *    the two radii are not equal 
     *    the two circles are coincident
     *    the two circles don't intersect
     * otherwise returns: array containing the two points of intersection of circleA and circleB
     */

    var R, centerA, centerB, D, h, h_;

    try {

        R = circleA.getRadius();
        centerA = circleA.getCenter();
        centerB = circleB.getCenter();

        if(R !== circleB.getRadius()) {
            throw( new Error("Radii are not equal.") );
        }
        if(centerA.equals(centerB)) {
            throw( new Error("Circle centres are coincident.") );
        }

        D = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(centerA, centerB); //Distance between the two centres (in meters)

        // Check that the two circles intersect
        if(D > (2 * R)) {
            throw( new Error("Circles do not intersect.") );
        }

        h = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(centerA, centerB); //Heading from centre of circle A to centre of circle B. (in degrees)
        h_ = Math.acos(D / 2 / R) * 180 / Math.PI; //Included angle between the intersections (for either of the two circles) (in degrees). This is trivial only because the two radii are equal.

        //Return an array containing the two points of intersection as google.maps.latLng objects
        return [
            google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(centerA, R, h + h_),
            google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(centerA, R, h - h_)
        ];
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error("getIntersections() :: " + e.message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

No disrespect to MBo by the way - it's an excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. What is surprising me is that your solution is more accurate on the map than MBo's even that you considered 2D!

Comment: Yazanpro, yes I played around with it a bit after posting and found the same. One thing to consider is that my solution is only 2D in one respect - the calculation of `h_` (MBo's `A`). I can only assume that the overall calcs are not particularly sensitive to this simplification and that the greater accuracy arises from using the google.maps.geometry.spherical API for `.computeDistanceBetween()', `.computeHeading()` and `.computeOffset()`. @MBo may have a view on this - he seems to understand the whole topic better than I (despite my solution's greater accuracy :-)).