# Find intersection coordinates of two circles on earth?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, earthdistance

I'm trying to find a second intersection point of two circles. One of the points that I already know was used to calculate a distance and then used as the circle radius ([exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff3Ff.png)). The problem is that im not getting the know point, im getting two new coordinates, even thou they are similar. The problem is probably related to the earth curvature but I have searched for some solution and found nothing.

The circles radius are calculated with the earth curvature. And this is the code I have:

```
function GET_coordinates_of_circles(position1,r1, position2,r2) {
  var deg2rad = function (deg) { return deg * (Math.PI / 180); };
  x1=position1.lng;
  y1=position1.lat;
  x2=position2.lng;
  y2=position2.lat;
  var centerdx = deg2rad(x1 - x2); 
  var centerdy = deg2rad(y1 - y2); 
  var R = Math.sqrt(centerdx * centerdx + centerdy * centerdy);

  if (!(Math.abs(r1 - r2) <= R && R <= r1 + r2)) { // no intersection
    console.log("nope");
    return []; // empty list of results
  }

  // intersection(s) should exist
  var R2 = R*R;
  var R4 = R2*R2;
  var a = (r1*r1 - r2*r2) / (2 * R2);
  var r2r2 = (r1*r1 - r2*r2);
  var c = Math.sqrt(2 * (r1*r1 + r2*r2) / R2 - (r2r2 * r2r2) / R4 - 1);

  var fx = (x1+x2) / 2 + a * (x2 - x1);
  var gx = c * (y2 - y1) / 2;
  var ix1 = fx + gx;
  var ix2 = fx - gx;

  var fy = (y1+y2) / 2 + a * (y2 - y1);
  var gy = c * (x1 - x2) / 2;
  var iy1 = fy + gy;
  var iy2 = fy - gy;
  // note if gy == 0 and gx == 0 then the circles are tangent and there is only one solution
  // but that one solution will just be duplicated as the code is currently written
  return [[iy1, ix1], [iy2, ix2]];
}
```

The deg2rad variable it is suppose to adjust the other calculations with the earth curvature.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi Filipe, welcome to SO. But this is a Math problem imho: https://math.stackexchange.com/ i wonder, because i could not link math exchange here via `flag` link >.>

Comment: I couldn't find any topic related, so im gonna create another question.
thank you for your time messerbill!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for R and so on are wrong because plane Pythagorean formula does not work for spherical trigonometry (for example - we can have triangle with all three right angles on the sphere!).  Instead we should use special formulas. Some of them are taken from [this  page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

At first find big circle arcs in radians for both radii using `R = Earth radius = 6,371km`

```
a1 = r1 / R
a2 = r2 / R
```

And distance (again arc in radians) between circle center using haversine formula

```
var R = 6371e3; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var ad = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
```

And bearing from position1 to position 2:

```
 //where    φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point 
 //(Δλ is the difference in longitude)
var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

Now look at the picture from my [answer considering equal radii case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469582/google-maps-two-circles-intersection-points/22553992#22553992).
(Here circle radii might be distinct and we should use another approach to find needed arcs)

[image]

We have spherical right-angle triangles ACB and FCB  (similar to plane case BD is perpendicular to AF in point C and BCA angle is right).
Spherical Pythagorean theorem (from the book on sph. trig) says that

```
 cos(AB) = cos(BC) * cos(AC)
 cos(FB) = cos(BC) * cos(FC)
```

or (using x for AC, y for BC and (ad-x) for FC)

```
 cos(a1) = cos(y) * cos(x)
 cos(a2) = cos(y) * cos(ad-x)
```

divide equations to eliminate cos(y)

```
 cos(a1)*cos(ad-x) = cos(a2) * cos(x)
 cos(a1)*(cos(ad)*cos(x) + sin(ad)*sin(x)) = cos(a2) * cos(x)
 cos(ad)*cos(x) + sin(ad)*sin(x) = cos(a2) * cos(x) / cos(a1)
 sin(ad)*sin(x) = cos(a2) * cos(x) / cos(a1) - cos(ad)*cos(x)
 sin(ad)*sin(x) = cos(x) * (cos(a2) / cos(a1) - cos(ad))
 TAC = tg(x) = (cos(a2) / cos(a1) - cos(ad)) / sin(ad)
```

Having hypotenuse and cathetus of ACB triangle we can find angle between AC and AB directions  (Napier's rules for right spherical triangles) - note we already know `TAC = tg(AC)` and `a1 = AB`

```
cos(CAB)= tg(AC) * ctg(AB)
CAB = Math.acos(TAC * ctg(a1))
```

Now we can calculate intersection points - they lie at arc distance a1 from position1 along bearings  `brng-CAB` and `brng+CAB`

```
B_bearing = brng - CAB
D_bearing = brng + CAB
```

Intersection points' coordinates:

```
var latB = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(a1) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(a1)*Math.cos(B_bearing) );
var lonB = lon1.toRad() + Math.atan2(Math.sin(B_bearing)*Math.sin(a1)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(a1)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

and the same for D_bearing

latB, lonB are in radians

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need ( [Intersection coordinates (lat/lon) of two circles (given the coordinates of the center and the radius) on earth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800285/intersection-coordinates-lat-lon-of-two-circles-given-the-coordinates-of-the) ) and hereby I share the solution in python in case it might help someone:

```py
'''
FINDING THE INTERSECTION COORDINATES (LAT/LON) OF TWO CIRCLES (GIVEN THE COORDINATES OF THE CENTER AND THE RADII)

Many thanks to Ture Pålsson who directed me to the right source, the code below is based on whuber's brilliant work here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/calculating-intersection-of-two-circles 

The idea is that;
  1. The points in question are the mutual intersections of three spheres: a sphere centered beneath location x1 (on the 
  earth's surface) of a given radius, a sphere centered beneath location x2 (on the earth's surface) of a given radius, and
  the earth itself, which is a sphere centered at O = (0,0,0) of a given radius.
  2. The intersection of each of the first two spheres with the earth's surface is a circle, which defines two planes.
  The mutual intersections of all three spheres therefore lies on the intersection of those two planes: a line.
  Consequently, the problem is reduced to intersecting a line with a sphere.

Note that "Decimal" is used to have higher precision which is important if the distance between two points are a few
meters.
'''
from decimal import Decimal
from math import cos, sin, sqrt
import math
import numpy as np

def intersection(p1, r1_meter, p2, r2_meter):
    # p1 = Coordinates of Point 1: latitude, longitude. This serves as the center of circle 1. Ex: (36.110174,  -90.953524)
    # r1_meter = Radius of circle 1 in meters
    # p2 = Coordinates of Point 2: latitude, longitude. This serves as the center of circle 1. Ex: (36.110174,  -90.953524)
    # r2_meter = Radius of circle 2 in meters
    '''
    1. Convert (lat, lon) to (x,y,z) geocentric coordinates.
    As usual, because we may choose units of measurement in which the earth has a unit radius
    '''
    x_p1 = Decimal(cos(math.radians(p1[1]))*cos(math.radians(p1[0])))  # x = cos(lon)*cos(lat)
    y_p1 = Decimal(sin(math.radians(p1[1]))*cos(math.radians(p1[0])))  # y = sin(lon)*cos(lat)
    z_p1 = Decimal(sin(math.radians(p1[0])))                           # z = sin(lat)
    x1 = (x_p1, y_p1, z_p1)

    x_p2 = Decimal(cos(math.radians(p2[1]))*cos(math.radians(p2[0])))  # x = cos(lon)*cos(lat)
    y_p2 = Decimal(sin(math.radians(p2[1]))*cos(math.radians(p2[0])))  # y = sin(lon)*cos(lat)
    z_p2 = Decimal(sin(math.radians(p2[0])))                           # z = sin(lat)
    x2 = (x_p2, y_p2, z_p2)
    '''
    2. Convert the radii r1 and r2 (which are measured along the sphere) to angles along the sphere.
    By definition, one nautical mile (NM) is 1/60 degree of arc (which is pi/180 * 1/60 = 0.0002908888 radians).
    '''
    r1 = Decimal(math.radians((r1_meter/1852) / 60)) # r1_meter/1852 converts meter to Nautical mile.
    r2 = Decimal(math.radians((r2_meter/1852) / 60))
    '''
    3. The geodesic circle of radius r1 around x1 is the intersection of the earth's surface with an Euclidean sphere
    of radius sin(r1) centered at cos(r1)*x1.

    4. The plane determined by the intersection of the sphere of radius sin(r1) around cos(r1)*x1 and the earth's surface
    is perpendicular to x1 and passes through the point cos(r1)x1, whence its equation is x.x1 = cos(r1)
    (the "." represents the usual dot product); likewise for the other plane. There will be a unique point x0 on the
    intersection of those two planes that is a linear combination of x1 and x2. Writing x0 = ax1 + b*x2 the two planar
    equations are;
       cos(r1) = x.x1 = (a*x1 + b*x2).x1 = a + b*(x2.x1)
       cos(r2) = x.x2 = (a*x1 + b*x2).x2 = a*(x1.x2) + b
    Using the fact that x2.x1 = x1.x2, which I shall write as q, the solution (if it exists) is given by
       a = (cos(r1) - cos(r2)*q) / (1 - q^2),
       b = (cos(r2) - cos(r1)*q) / (1 - q^2).
    '''
    q = Decimal(np.dot(x1, x2))

    if q**2 != 1 :
        a = (Decimal(cos(r1)) - Decimal(cos(r2))*q) / (1 - q**2)
        b = (Decimal(cos(r2)) - Decimal(cos(r1))*q) / (1 - q**2)
        '''
        5. Now all other points on the line of intersection of the two planes differ from x0 by some multiple of a vector
        n which is mutually perpendicular to both planes. The cross product  n = x1~Cross~x2  does the job provided n is 
        nonzero: once again, this means that x1 and x2 are neither coincident nor diametrically opposite. (We need to 
        take care to compute the cross product with high precision, because it involves subtractions with a lot of
        cancellation when x1 and x2 are close to each other.)
        '''
        n = np.cross(x1, x2)
        '''
        6. Therefore, we seek up to two points of the form x0 + t*n which lie on the earth's surface: that is, their length
        equals 1. Equivalently, their squared length is 1:  
        1 = squared length = (x0 + t*n).(x0 + t*n) = x0.x0 + 2t*x0.n + t^2*n.n = x0.x0 + t^2*n.n
        '''
        x0_1 = [a*f for f in x1]
        x0_2 = [b*f for f in x2]
        x0 = [sum(f) for f in zip(x0_1, x0_2)]
        '''
          The term with x0.n disappears because x0 (being a linear combination of x1 and x2) is perpendicular to n.
          The two solutions easily are   t = sqrt((1 - x0.x0)/n.n)    and its negative. Once again high precision
          is called for, because when x1 and x2 are close, x0.x0 is very close to 1, leading to some loss of
          floating point precision.
        '''
        if (np.dot(x0, x0) <= 1) & (np.dot(n,n) != 0): # This is to secure that (1 - np.dot(x0, x0)) / np.dot(n,n) > 0
            t = Decimal(sqrt((1 - np.dot(x0, x0)) / np.dot(n,n)))
            t1 = t
            t2 = -t

            i1 = x0 + t1*n
            i2 = x0 + t2*n
            '''
            7. Finally, we may convert these solutions back to (lat, lon) by converting geocentric (x,y,z) to geographic
            coordinates. For the longitude, use the generalized arctangent returning values in the range -180 to 180
            degrees (in computing applications, this function takes both x and y as arguments rather than just the
            ratio y/x; it is sometimes called "ATan2").
            '''

            i1_lat = math.degrees( math.asin(i1[2]))
            i1_lon = math.degrees( math.atan2(i1[1], i1[0] ) )
            ip1 = (i1_lat, i1_lon)

            i2_lat = math.degrees( math.asin(i2[2]))
            i2_lon = math.degrees( math.atan2(i2[1], i2[0] ) )
            ip2 = (i2_lat, i2_lon)
            return [ip1, ip2]
        elif (np.dot(n,n) == 0):
            return("The centers of the circles can be neither the same point nor antipodal points.")
        else:
            return("The circles do not intersect")
    else:
        return("The centers of the circles can be neither the same point nor antipodal points.")

'''
Example: The output of below is  [(36.989311051533505, -88.15142628069133), (38.2383796094578, -92.39048549120287)]

         intersection_points = intersection((37.673442, -90.234036), 107.5*1852, (36.109997, -90.953669), 145*1852)
         print(intersection_points)
'''
```

Any feedback is appreciated.